# Bulk hive table creation in Google Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am very new to Google Cloud Platform, and I am doing a POC for moving a hive application (tables and jobs) to Google Dataproc. The data has already been moved to Google cloud Storage.

Is there an inbuilt way to create all the tables from hive in dataproc in bulk, instead of creating one by one using the hive prompt?

Comment: I know I can precreate all the hive DDLs in a file and put it in GCS, and then use beeline to run this file, but is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataproc support Hive job type, so you can use the gcloud command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=CLUSTER \
   -e 'create table t1 (id int, name string); create table t2 ...;'
```

or

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=CLUSTER -f create_tables.hql
```

You can also SSH into the master node, then use beeline to execute the script:

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 -f create_tables.hql
```

Comment: Thanks @Dagang for your answer. What do you think would be the best way to fire any of these commands, as I will have to automate the entire process. Can I create a dataproc workflow that runs any of the above commands, or if do you have any other better approach, please share!

Comment: There are many ways to automate the commands, depending on your use case. You can consider Dataproc Workflow, Cloud Composer, Terraform, simple shell script running from another GCE VM, etc.